# How use "Long" type in an MongoDB schema declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I guess it's a stupid question but i would like do something like this

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Long = require("long");
 
 var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: Long(),
  name: String,
  completed: Long(),
  note: String,
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 });
```

But it's not working,"cannot set 'low' property". I know that cause I do not pass arguments in the "Long" constructor but it's not working iven if I don't put the "()". I'm a bit lost with that ^^'

Sorry for my english ^^'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a module specifically designed for Mongoose, like [`mongoose-long`](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-long):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
var Long = mongoose.Schema.Types.Long;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id         : Long,
  name       : String,
  completed  : Long,
  note       : String,
  updated_at : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

Comment: By the way, I'm working with node for a school project and I've to do a link between "Post" and "Comment" entity, do you think I've to declare an "id" field like I did in my exemple or just an "foreignId" one? ^^'

Comment: All documents in MongoDB will automatically get a unique `_id` property assigned to them, which you can use. More information on how to do that with Mongoose can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).